# How to separate axios call from component in react native?

Tags: react-native, axios

I am new to react native. I have following component in my project for now I have written for fetching API in same component but want to separate it out. I am getting difficulty for how can i access variable which I am using in "getAlbum" method from outside of component.

Is there standard way to separate API call from component?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  FlatList, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { ActivityIndicator, Provider } from 'react-native-paper';
import axios from 'axios';
import styles from '../style/ThumbnailView.component.style';
import ErrorAlert from '../common/ErrorAlert';
import * as myConstant from '../common/Constants';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {

  // For to Navigation header
  static navigationOptions = () => ({
    headerTitle: 'Album Information',
  });

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      apiLoadingError: false,
    };
  }

  getAlbums() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const albumId = navigation.getParam('albumID', 'no data');
    axios
      .get(
        myConstant.API + `photos?albumId=${albumId}`, {timeout: myConstant.TIMEOUT} 
      )
      .then((response) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: response.data,
          });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({isLoading: false, apiLoadingError: true})
      }); 
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAlbums();
  }

  render() {

    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 30 }}>
            <ActivityIndicator animating={true} size='large' />
        </View>
      );
    }

    if (this.state.apiLoadingError) {
      return (
        <ErrorAlert />
      );
    }

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Provider>
          <View style={styles.listContainer} >

            <FlatList
                testID='flatlist'
                data={ this.state.dataSource } numColumns={3}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <View style={styles.listRowContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('AlbumDetailsViewScreen', {
                  albumTitle: item.title, albumImg: item.url
                })} style={styles.listRow}>
                    <View style={styles.listTextNavVIew}>
                      <Image source = {{ uri: item.thumbnailUrl }} style={styles.imageViewContainer} />
                    </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              }
                keyExtractor = { (item, index) => index.toString() }
            />

          </View>
        </Provider>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: You can use redux, context API or AsyncStorage in order to store & access value from different components. Also, create an Axios instance & use that instance across multiple components without using Axios everywhere.

Comment: @SDushan can you please provide example for context API?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your axios call by making another class with function which will receive 'albumID' as an argument - then add it to your axios link. If you want to call this function from another class just make it static and use like in example below. Then you can map your fetchData to parse it into state. Hope it will help you.

```
export class Api {
    static fetchData = (albumId: string) => {
        //here your axios call which will return an array
    }
}

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    state = {
        //.....
    }

    receivedData = Api.fetchData('albumID');
    //you can map array here to get what you want.
}
```